# TypeError: User() got unexpected keyword arguments: 'password2' : Django JWT Authentication

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, jwt

I am trying to build a user authentication app using django JWT token, when i try to test my user authentication api and validate the `password` and `password2` , it generate the following error:

```
TypeError: User() got unexpected keyword arguments: 'password2'
```

My `serializers.py` is as follows:

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from account.models import User

class UserRegistrationSerializers(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    password2=serializers.CharField(style={'input_type':'password'}, write_only=True)
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields=['email','name','tc','password','password2']
        extra_kwargs={
            'password':{'write_only':True}
        }

def validate(self, attrs):
    password=attrs.get('password')
    password2=attrs.get('password2')
    if password != password2:
        raise serializer.ValidationError("Password and Confirm Password Does not match")
    return attrs

def validate_data(self, validate_data):
    return User.objects.create_user(**validate_data)
```

and my `views.py` is as follows:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from rest_framework.response import Response
from rest_framework import status
from rest_framework.views import APIView
from account.serializers import UserRegistrationSerializers


# Create your views here.
class UserRegistrationView(APIView):
    def post(self, request, format=None):
        serializer=  UserRegistrationSerializers(data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True):
            user= serializer.save()
            return Response({'msg':'Registration Successful'}, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

my `models.py` file is as follows:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import BaseUserManager, AbstractBaseUser
# Create your models here.

class UserManager(BaseUserManager):
    def create_user(self, email, name, tc, password=None, password2=None):
        """
        Creates and saves a User with the given email, date of
        birth and password.
        """
        if not email:
            raise ValueError('Users must have an email address')

        user = self.model(
            email=self.normalize_email(email),
            name=name,
            tc=tc,
        )

        user.set_password(password)
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user

    def create_superuser(self, email, name, tc, password=None):
        """
        Creates and saves a superuser with the given email, date of
        birth and password.
        """
        user = self.create_user(
            email,
            password=password,
            name=name,
            tc=tc,
        )
        user.is_admin = True
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user
class User(AbstractBaseUser):
    email = models.EmailField(
        verbose_name='Email',
        max_length=255,
        unique=True,
    )
    #date_of_birth = models.DateField()
    name= models.CharField(max_length=200)
    tc=models.BooleanField()
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    is_admin = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    created_at=models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at=models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    objects = UserManager()

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['name','tc']

    def __str__(self):
        return self.email

    def has_perm(self, perm, obj=None):
        "Does the user have a specific permission?"
        # Simplest possible answer: Yes, always
        return self.is_admin

    def has_module_perms(self, app_label):
        "Does the user have permissions to view the app `app_label`?"
        # Simplest possible answer: Yes, always
        return True

    @property
    def is_staff(self):
        "Is the user a member of staff?"
        # Simplest possible answer: All admins are staff
        return self.is_admin
```

The full `traceback` is as follows:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "D:\jwt\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 55,
> in inner
> response = get_response(request)   File "D:\jwt\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 197, in
> _get_response
> response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)   File "D:\jwt\lib\site-packages\django\views\decorators\csrf.py", line 54,
> in wrapped_view
> return view_func(*args, **kwargs)   File "D:\jwt\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\base.py", line 103, in
> view
> return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)   File "D:\jwt\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py", line 509, in
> dispatch
> response = self.handle_exception(exc)   File "D:\jwt\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py", line 469, in
> handle_exception
> self.raise_uncaught_exception(exc)   File "D:\jwt\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py", line 480, in
> raise_uncaught_exception
> raise exc   File "D:\jwt\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py", line 506, in
> dispatch
> response = handler(request, *args, **kwargs)   File "D:\djangoauthapi1\account\views.py", line 13, in post
> user= serializer.save()   File "D:\jwt\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\serializers.py", line 212, in
> save
> self.instance = self.create(validated_data)   File "D:\jwt\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\serializers.py", line 981, in
> create
> raise TypeError(msg) TypeError: Got a `TypeError` when calling `User.objects.create()`. This may be because you have a writable field
> on the serializer class that is not a valid argument to
> `User.objects.create()`. You may need to make the field read-only, or
> override the UserRegistrationSerializers.create() method to handle
> this correctly. Original exception was:  Traceback (most recent call
> last):   File
> "D:\jwt\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\serializers.py", line 962, in
> create
> instance = ModelClass._default_manager.create(**validated_data)   File "D:\jwt\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\manager.py", line 85,
> in manager_method    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args,
> **kwargs)   File "D:\jwt\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 669, in create
> obj = self.model(**kwargs)   File "D:\jwt\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 565, in
> **init**
> raise TypeError( TypeError: User() got unexpected keyword arguments: 'password2'

i have figured out each line of code but i am unable to catch what is exactly the error, please needful help is required.

Comment: I'm unfamiliar with django but where do you call validate? Do you pass a dict, or keyword args? If it's the latter, then `attrs` needs to be `**attrs`

Comment: I have tried your suggestion but it is giving the error of syntax

Comment: Can you share the full traceback?

Comment: @SunderamDubey i have edited the question with full traceback as you acquired.

Comment: @SunderamDubey `password2=serializers.CharField(style={'input_type':'password'}, read_only=True)`  , i have edited this line in `serializers.py` the error is gone, but it is not validating the two passwords, even if the password does not match it is still adding in the table with success message, but that is not required, it should give the validation error , still stuck please help

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because your serializer has `password2` but User model does not have.

Just pop password2 into validated_data

```py
from rest_framework import serializers
from account.models import User

class UserRegistrationSerializers(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    password2=serializers.CharField(style={'input_type':'password'}, write_only=True)
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields=['email','name','tc','password','password2']
        extra_kwargs={
            'password':{'write_only':True}
        }

def validate(self, attrs):
    password=attrs.get('password')
    password2=attrs.pop('password2')
    if password != password2:
        raise serializer.ValidationError("Password and Confirm Password Does not match")
    return attrs

def create(self, validate_data):
    return User.objects.create_user(**validate_data)
```

Comment: still the problem persist and error is the same.

Comment: Did you change `def validated_data` to `def create` ?

Comment: i have copy pasted exactly your code in the `serializer.py`, but problem persist.

Comment: my bad actually there was an indentation issue, both the function `def create` and `def were not inside the `class UserRegistrationSerializers`, Thank you problem resolved.

Comment: popping password2 did the trick. thank you.

Answer (score 0):

IN serializers.py file your validate and validate_data must be inside of UserRegistrationSerializers class and must be outside of Meta class other things is al right.Example:

```
class UserRegistrationSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

  password2 = serializers.CharField(style={'input_type':'password'}, write_only=True)
  class Meta:
    model = User
    fields=['email', 'name', 'password', 'password2', 'tc']
    extra_kwargs={
      'password':{'write_only':True}
    }


  def validate(self, attrs):
    password = attrs.get('password')
    password2 = attrs.get('password2')
    if password != password2:
      raise serializers.ValidationError("Password and Confirm Password doesn't match")
    return attrs

  def validate_data(self, validate_data):
    return User.objects.create_user(**validate_data)
```